# Is it a nicer way for destructuring object property?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable `label`. The property `label` can be absent inside `options[0]`. I use optional chaining operator here. Is there a nicer way for destructuring label property?

The code looks like this:

```js
const label = screenItems.vendor.options[0]?.label
```

Comment: You're not destructuring here, but destructuring would look *really* ugly. Your current code looks perfect (assuming it works)

Comment: yeah, it works.

Comment: "optional chaining operator" has this been released?

Comment: looks like stage4. we use babel transpiler inside our project.

Comment: @EugeneSunic No, but there are currently some environments that have implemented it (e.g. I've just tested in Chrome 79, and it works). And it can be made to work anywhere using a transpiler like Babel...

Comment: Should be available in ES2020 I believe.

Answer (score 2):

> You are not destructuring here. and that code should work fine...

But if you really want to destructure your solution. Use the snippet below...

```
  // assuming you have `screenItems.vendor.options` defined already
  const options = screenItems.vendor.options

  const { label } = options.length > 0 ? options[0] : {}

  if (label) {
    // all the code that requires the label
  }
```

which is much more code in this case too.

Comment: It will throw TypeError in case options[0] is undefined.

Comment: Note that the OP's code won't throw if the `screenItems.vendor.options` doesn't have a property called `0`, but yours will...

Comment: I have tested in chrome-snippets... and should work if `screenItems.vendor.options` is defined in the scope

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether it is nicer, but you could do nested [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
const obj = {
    screenitems: {
    vendor: {
        options: null
    }
  }
}

const obj2 = {
    screenitems: {
    vendor: {
        options: [{label:"LABEL"}]
    }
  }
}

const { screenitems: {vendor: {options} }} = obj2;
const label = options?options[0].label:"No"
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5n0g1bue/9/)